# changing value of cell on condition in gridview - c#

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

I have fetched the data from SQL server to datagridview but I don't know how to change the cell value. I have to change the fetched value 1 and 0 to available and unavailable. here is my code for fetching data ... please help.

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = 192.168.100.6;Database=sms;UID=sa;Password=1234;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id as 'Book ID',name as 'Name' , status as 'Status' from book where Name = @name", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtFirstName.Text);
        try
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
            bsource.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
        }
        catch (Exception ec)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
        }

    //    chage_value();
        dataGridView1.Show();

    }

}
```

Comment: please clarify its GridView or DataGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below answer

```
  private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = 192.168.100.6;Database=sms;UID=sa;Password=1234;");
string sSql=@"Select id as 'Book ID',name as 'Name' , 
           Case when status=0 then 'unavailable' else 'available '
           End as 'Status' from 
           book where Name ='"+txtFirstName.Text +"'" 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, con); 
            try
            {

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
            }

        //    chage_value();
            dataGridView1.Show();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to store your queries in variables. This will help you in the long run. Also, it is good practise to check whether you are connected or not before trying to send a query away to the server. It is important to remeber that when you fetch data from your server, it will most likely be seen as a string, so if you want to compare it as a number, you need to convert it first.

What you could do is something similar to what i've written below. You count the amount of answers your query returns, then loop through them and check whether they are 0 or 1. Then just replace the value with `Avaliable` or `Unavaliable`.

```
if (dbCon.IsConnect()){
            MySqlCommand idCmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from " + da.DataGridView1.Text, dbCon.Connection);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = idCmd.ExecuteReader()){
              //  List<string> stringArray = new List<string>(); // you could use this string array to compare them, if you like this approach more.
                while (reader.Read()){
                    var checkStatus= reader["Status"].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + checkStatus.Split(' ').Count()); //checks how many items you've got.
                    foreach (var item in checkStatus.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray()){
                        var item2 = 0.0; // your 0 or 1 for avaliable or unavaliable..
                        try{
                            item2 = double.Parse(item.ToString());
                            if(strcmp(item2,'0') == 1){ //assuming you only have 0's and 1's.
                              item2 = "unavaliable";
                            }else{
                              item2 = "avaliable";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception){
                            //do what you want
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("item: " + item2);
                    }
                }
                dbCon.Close();
            }
        }
        return //what you want;
}
```